# Trigger a runner everyday in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, jobs, runner

So I want to trigger a Runner to generate something and insert it into MongoDb. I want to do it in nodejs. Are there any libraries help me do that??

Currently I am using express making a api server, haven't found a way to do that yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron).

Comment: @nilveryboring Did I answer your question?